# Type alias in Flow that's equivalent to "An array of dictionaries"

Tags: javascript, flowtype

If my data is:

```
[
    {
      key1: true,
      key2: "value1"
    },

    {
      key1: false,
      key2: "value2"
    },
  ];
```

What kind of custom flow type should I declare that conforms to it?

```
type MyType = // .... ?
```

Answer (score 0):

To define the type of `data`, you can use [`Array<MyType>` type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/arrays/#toc-array-type) where `MyType` is the type of elements in the array.

You can define the type alias `MyType` for the objects in the array using [exact object types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types).

Remember that **exact object types** are the *opposite* of [explicit inexact object types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-explicit-inexact-object-types), which we discussed in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353038/type-alias-in-flow-with-brackets-and-ellipsis). This means that objects of type `MyType` must explicitly *only* have the keys `key1: boolean` and `key2: string`.

Here's the full Flow annotation:

```js
/* @flow */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} MyType an exact object type with two keys
 * @see {@link https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types}
 * @property {boolean} key1
 * @property {string} key2
 */
type MyType = {|
    key1: boolean,
    key2: string,
|}

/**
 * @type {Array<MyType>}
 */
const data: Array<MyType> = [
  {
    key1: true,
    key2: "value1"
  },
  {
    key1: false,
    key2: "value2"
  },
]
```

If you want to alias a type for `data` as well, then you can define it as such:

```js
/* @flow */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} MyObjectType an exact object type with two keys
 * @see {@link https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types}
 * @property {boolean} key1
 * @property {string} key2
 */
type MyObjectType = {|
    key1: boolean,
    key2: string,
|}

/**
 * @typedef {Array<MyObjectType>} MyType array type for an array of objects pf type "MyObjectType"
 * @see {@link https://flow.org/en/docs/types/arrays/#toc-array-type}
 * @todo alternatively can be defined as "type MyType = MyObjectType[]"
 */ 
type MyType = Array<MyObjectType>

/**
 * @type {Array<MyType>}
 */
const data: MyType = [
  {
    key1: true,
    key2: "value1"
  },
  {
    key1: false,
    key2: "value2"
  },
]
```