# Type alias in flow with brackets and ellipsis

Tags: javascript, flowtype

```
type WeirdCustomType = {[int]: boolean, ...};
```

What kind of structure is `WeirdCustomType`? Is it simply an array of `{int:boolean}` types ? (ie, key is an int, value is a boolean)? If so, what is the meaning of ... here? And where can I read about this particular type aliasing usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WeirdCustomType` is an “[Explicit inexact object type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-explicit-inexact-object-types)”

Its properties consist of:

- A) properties with integer keys with boolean values

  - the brackets around `int` indicate that we’re referring to the property keys, and that those keys are of type `int` (which should actually be `number`, see last section of my answer)
  - this follows destructuring syntax for objects and their keys, and you can read more about “[Computed object property names and destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)” on the MDN docs
- B) additional properties with other keys and value types

Here’s how an object of `WeirdCustomType` may look:

```js
const inexactObject: WeirdObjectType = {
  1: ‘foo’,
  2: ‘bar’,
  baz: ‘abc’
}
```

The ellipses on `WeirdCustomType` indicate explicitly (to make it extra clear) that this type allows for an object with extra properties where a normal object type is expected.

To disable that behavior, you can use the [exact object type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types). As described in the documentation,

> Unlike regular object types, it is not valid to pass an object with “extra” properties to an exact object type.

```js
// @flow
var foo: {| foo: string |} = { foo: "Hello", bar: "World!" }; // Error!
```

Here’s a [post on Medium](https://medium.com/flow-type/on-the-roadmap-exact-objects-by-default-16b72933c5cf) that explains the motivation.

> Currently, `{foo: number}` is the type for any object which has a property `foo` with type `number`. `{| foo: number |}` is the type for an object which ONLY has a property `foo` with type `number`. We say the former syntax is an inexact object and the latter is an exact object.
>
> In a few releases, Flow will begin to treat `{foo: number}` as an exact object. To indicate inexactness, you must add an ellipsis to the end of an object type: `{foo: number, ...}`. This new syntax forces the developers to opt in to inexactness.

#### note on `int` type

Flow doesn’t actually have a primitive type `int`. Integers are represented by the `number` type. I believe that the `[int]` should be `[number]`.

See https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/

Comment: Thanks. I'm still confused about the [] around int. Why does that mean it refer to property keys ? Doesn't [] mean it's an array or tuple ?

Comment: Have you read through the documentation for destructuring? If it was not in brackets, the key would be parsed to literally be “the key ‘number’ should have a value that is a boolean”. Putting it in brackets changes the meaning to “for keys that are of a ‘number’ type, the value should be a boolean.”

Comment: And it *is* referring to an array of keys since `{ [number]: boolean }` means “all properties in the object for which the keys are of type `number`, the value should be a `boolean`.